# Triple IF Statement in Windows Batch File? IF and IF and IF? Else Errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I am very very new to Windows batch files, so sorry if this is totally obvious.

Basically, in a batch file, I need a triple IF statement that checks if 3 parameters have been given on the command line. If they are there, it uses GOTO to execute more code. If it doesn't have all three, then it echoes the error.

This is the code I have so far, that doesn't work

```
IF defined %1% (
  IF defined %2% (
    IF defined %3% (
    GOTO copyoutvariables
    ELSE GOTO parametererror 
    )
  )
)

:parametererror
Echo You did not enter the right amount of parameters.

:copyoutvariables
Echo Irrelevant Code goes here.
```

If I enter three parameters then it goes straight to `:parametererror`.

I think the syntax for the `ELSE` is wrong. I don't really know where it should go though.
Is there a better way to format the triple IF?
Is there a way to AND my IF's?
And where should the ELSE statement be?

Comment: Are **really** using MS-DOS or are you talking about batch files for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have several issues:

- `IF defined` can only be applied to environment variables, NOT Batch file parameters.
- Your `%1%` construction is wrong, because `%1` is replaced by the first parameter, if any, and the second `%` is just ignored.
- The right way to check if a parameter was given is: `IF "%~1" equ "" echo Parameter 1 not given`.
- You not need to check if both `%1` and `%2` parameters was given; just to check if `%3` is given. This way, your code may be reduced to this one:

.

```
IF "%~3" neq "" (
   GOTO copyoutvariables
) ELSE (
   GOTO parametererror
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew my code was pretty damn terrible, and this is the best explanation as to why, and it worked!  Great Answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's your bracketing, based on some distant memory.

Try:

```
IF defined %1% IF defined %2% IF defined %3% 
(
    GOTO :copyoutvariables
)    
ELSE 
(
    GOTO :parametererror 
)

:parametererror
Echo You did not enter the right amount of parameters.

:copyoutvariables
Echo Irrelevant Code goes here.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This will fail as the parenthesis must be on the same line. `IF ... (` and `) ELSE (`. But the combined `IF defined %1% IF defined ...` looks good

Comment: Ah, thank you. It's been a while, so it's nice to see I'm not completely wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple more parentheses around the `ELSE`.

```
IF defined %1% (
  IF defined %2% (
    IF defined %3% (
      GOTO copyoutvariables
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO parametererror 
    )
  )
)
```